# Desc <table-name> not working in oracle 11g client

Tags: oracle11g

Desc  is throwing invalid sql statement in oracle 11g client.`enter code here`

Comment: Show the exact statement you typed and the exact error message.  Are you using SQLPlus? Put it in the original post by using the edit link.  “In a dark place we find ourselves, and a little more knowledge lights our way.”

– Yoda

Comment: @Gary_W I am using PL/SQL Developer and using command desc wms_attribute_type;    The error I am getting is ORA-00900:invalid SQL Statement. In a pop up window.

Comment: in a SQL Window or a Command Window? it's only working in a Command Window

Comment: Thanks @Thomas !!  It works!!

Comment: @Thomas please put your comment in an answer so Preethi can mark it as the answer and you can get credit for it, plus future searchers will know what worked.

Comment: @Preethi Jha no problem :)

Comment: @Gary_W thanks, i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be a short answer :)

it's only working in a Command Window in PL/SQL Developer